# Is the contraction of a minimal prime of the extension always the original prime?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A\subseteq B$ be finite-type integral $k$-algebras, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Suppose we have a prime $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ and $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq B$ a minimal prime of $\mathfrak{p}B$. Is it then always true that $\mathfrak{q}\cap A=\mathfrak{p}$? Only the inclusion $\mathfrak{q}\cap A\supseteq\mathfrak{p}$ is obvious. I suspect it is false, although I couldn't come up with a counter example.

**Edit:** Note that I don't consider an example where the extension $\mathfrak{p}B$ is the unit ideal $\mathfrak{p}B=(1)$ a counterexample. This is because then the set of minimal primes $\min(\mathfrak{p}B)$ of $\mathfrak{p}B$ is empty, and thus the statement
$$
\forall \mathfrak{q}\in\min(\mathfrak{p}B):\ \mathfrak{q}\cap A=\mathfrak{p}
$$
is vacuously true.

Comment: $A = k[x] \subseteq k[x,y]/(xy) = B$, $\mathfrak{p} = 0$, $\mathfrak{q} = (x)$

Comment: @math54321 Thanks, but note that I'm looking for integral examples, and in your example $B$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: OK, then take e.g. $k[x] \subseteq k[x, x^{-1}]$

Comment: @math54321 And what prime ideals? If we take $\mathfrak{p}=(x)$ then the extension of $\mathfrak{p}$ is $(1)$, which has no minimal prime. Hence for $\mathfrak{p}=(x)$, the statement is vacuously true.

Comment: Alright, let's see if 3rd time's the charm: $A = k[x,xy] \subseteq k[x,y] = B$, $\mathfrak{p} = xA$, so that $\mathfrak{p}B \cap A = (x, xy)$

Comment: If you also want an example where $\mathfrak{p}$ is actually in the image of $\operatorname{Spec}(B) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, you can take $A = k[x,y] \subseteq k[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz) = B$, $\mathfrak{p} = (x)$, $\mathfrak{q} = (x,y)$

Comment: @math54321 Thanks, these are great examples! I think I see now what is going on geometrically. 3rd and 4th time are the charm :) If you want you can post it as an answer and I will like and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example where $\mathfrak{p}$ is *not* a contraction of a prime of $B$: take $A = k[x,xy] \subseteq k[x,y] = B$, and $\mathfrak{p} = xA$, so that $\mathfrak{p} B \cap A = (x, xy)A \supsetneq \mathfrak{p}$. (This is a classic example of a map of affine varieties with constructible but non-closed image).

For an example where $\mathfrak{p}$ *is* a contraction of a prime of $B$: take $A = k[x,y] \subseteq k[x,y,z,w]/(xw - yz) = B$, and $\mathfrak{p} = xA$, so that $\mathfrak{p} B = (x, xw - yz)B = (x, yz)B$, which has 2 minimal primes $\{ (x, y)B, (x, z)B \}$, and $(x, y)B \cap A = (x, y)A \supsetneq \mathfrak{p}$. (Note: this is the blowup of the affine plane at the origin.)

Answer (score 1):

At least, without the hypothesis on $k$ being algebraically closed, you have the counter example with $A = \mathbb Z$ and $B = \mathbb Q$ : 
$\mathfrak p = 3 \mathbb Z$. 
Then $\mathfrak q = 3 \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q$ and $\mathfrak q \cap \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z \ne \mathfrak p$.

Adding the hypothesis i don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I don't think that it works though. The extension $\mathfrak{p}^e$ is the unit ideal $\mathfrak{p}^e=(1)$, and by definition the unit ideal is not prime. Hence there are no minimal primes $\mathfrak{q}$ to test for, so the statement is vacuously true.